# Get the full path of the symlink target in Ansible

Tags: ansible

How do I get the full path of a symlink target in Ansible? I'm trying to cleanup a folder--delete files older than *x* number of days but I don't want to remove the target of a particular file symlink. My plan is to get the symlink target and then use the value as an exclude target when using the `find` module.

The symlink target changes from time to time. I tried using the `stat` module but it doesn't solve my requirement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`stat` module returns `lnk_source` and `lnk_target` which should do the trick.

---

##### Pay attention to confusing names:

- `lnk_source` => [**Target** of the symlink normalized for the remote filesystem](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html#return-stat/lnk_source)
- `lnk_target` => [**Target** of the symlink. Note that relative paths remain relative](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html#return-stat/lnk_target)

For the **actual SOURCE of the symlink**, well, it's just `path`.

Comment: Thanks for this! I used `follow: yes` in the playbook that's why I didn't see the `lnk_source` and `lnk_target` in the `stat` output.

Comment: The names are somewhat confusing, but `lnk_source` is the full path (what the asker wants here), while `lnk_target` may be a relative path.

Comment: There's some discussion on this at [stat module doesn't return lnk_source when follow=yes](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/3427).

Comment: Ansible stat docs can be found here:  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html

Comment: @EM0 yeah exactly. Those name are just WRONG. This is NOT about the actual source and target of the link, and it costs me so much time!